# numpy tile without memory allocation

Tags: python, numpy, memory, matrix, tile

I am thinking about a way that using `np.tile` but without allocating memory for a new matrix. Is there possibly a way to achieve this?

Being a bit verbose, the functions I am seeking is as follow:

```
a = np.random.rand(4,)
b = np.random.rand(8,)
c = np.tile(a,2) + b # this generate a memory copy anyhow
```

I want to avoid the memory copy of the `np.tile`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
c = (b.reshape(2,4)+a).ravel()
```

The reshape and ravel are both views, so (I think) the only new array is produced by the summation.  In effect I am changing `b` to a shape that can be broadcasted with `a`.

This is measureably faster, even in this small problem.

---

`broadcast_array` lets you do the broadcasting in steps

```
In [506]: b1,a1 = np.broadcast_arrays(b.reshape(2,4),a)
```

`a1` is a view, as shown by the data buffer pointer

```
In [507]: a1.__array_interface__['data']
Out[507]: (164774704, False)
In [508]: a.__array_interface__['data']
Out[508]: (164774704, False)
```

The sum

```
In [509]: a1+b1
Out[509]: 
array([[ 2.04663934,  1.02951915,  1.30616273,  1.75154236],
       [ 1.79237632,  1.08252741,  1.17031265,  1.2675438 ]])
```

`a1` has, effectively, been tiled without copying

```
In [511]: a1.shape
Out[511]: (2, 4)
In [512]: a1.strides
Out[512]: (0, 8)
```

Look at the `np.lib.stride_tricks.py` file for more details on this sort of broadcasting.  `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` is the underlying function that lets you construct a view with new shape and strides.  It's been used most often on SO to construct sliding windows.